# Reducing network requests within Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

Our team uses Kafka as my message queuing tech and due to the high-volume of fast & small messages, throttling is kicking in and causing a variety of issues within our producers.

I'm looking to reduce the number of requests being made to the broker in an attempt to remove this throttling. The main thing I've looked into is the `batch.size` and `linger.ms` applied to each producer within the pipeline and have set them to about `1mb` and `500ms` respectively. I'm just curious what things I should be looking into to fix this.

Comment: I can only think of `compression.type` in addition to the two settings you've already  mentioned.